# Jasmine mock ajax calls not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, tdd, jasmine

I tried writing a spec that allows Ajax calls to be mocked out. The test case works perfectly fine on browsers like Chrome and Firefox. But I am facing some issues when I run the test case on IE (version 9,10). This issue arises when the normal Ajax calls are made using jQuery Ajax.

I get an error in IE as follows:

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'response': object is null or undefined.
```

The test case that I have written is as follows

```
   describe("mocking ajax", function() {

   beforeEach(function() {
     jasmine.Ajax.install();
   });

   afterEach(function() {
     jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
   });

   it("specifying response when you need it", function() {
        var doneFn = jasmine.createSpy("success");

        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
          url :"/any/service",
          success : function(data){
          doneFn(data);
        }
     });

     expect(doneFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

     jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().response({
        "status": 200,
        "contentType": 'text/plain',
        "responseText": 'awesome response'
     });

     expect(doneFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('awesome response');
 });

});
```

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle version that is runnable in chrome and not in said version of ie?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jasmine-ajax? There has been an issue raised about this on the github repo seems to have been fixed by a recent pull request.

[IE Issue jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax/issues/56)

Comment: I think that issue was raised by tiger :)